# Gnome Terminal Receiving Incorrect Character Input

Tags: command-line, gnome, keyboard, gnome-terminal

While typing in my terminal, I discovered that the "b" key is no longer working. When I type the letter 'b', the terminal interprets it as the sequence of characters '"C": forward-word'. The 'b' key works correctly in other applications (e.g. as I type it to you now) and even capital 'B' works correctly in the terminal.

How can I get the terminal to correctly interpret this key? I haven't changed any settings recently, and to the best of my knowledge this key had been working correctly in the terminal since I got the computer about a month ago.

Comment: Do you have a `~/.inputrc` file in your home directory (or have you modified `/etc/inputrc`)? what does `bind -p | grep '^"b"'` output?

Comment: Ah, I did have a `~/.inputrc` file and clearing it has fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong syntax in my `~/.inputrc` file which led to this behavior. Clearing the `~/.inputrc` file fixed the problem.